# composer autoload file after classmaps are loaded

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I have

```
"autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "ACME": "src/",
      },
      "classmap": ["src/"],
      "files": ["mapper.php"],
      "exclude-from-classmap": ["mapper.php"]
  },
```

in `mapper.php` I'm trying to give different namespaces for some legacy stuff.

```
<?php
class_alias(Some_Class::class, 'Cool\NameSpaced\Class');
```

I think this fails to build because `mapper.php` is using classes in `src/` and they have not been loaded by composer yet. Is there a way to do this?

Command that I run is `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried you example and it works well.

It might be related to composer command you use. **Try this one instead**:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

**This will refresh anything from `autoload` section.**

Here is the setup file by file:

#### `composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/"],
        "files": ["mapper.php"]
    }
}
```

#### `mapper.php`

```
<?php

class_alias(Some_Class::class, 'Cool\NameSpaced\Class');
```

#### `index.php`

```
<?php 

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

var_dump(class_exists(Some_Class::class));
var_dump(class_exists('Cool\NameSpaced\Class'));
```

#### Test in CLI

```
$ composer dump-autoload
$ php index.php
bool(true);
bool(true);
```

---

### How to find out aliasing works?

#### `commposer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/"]
    }
}
```

#### Test in CLI

```
$ composer dump-autoload
$ php index.php
bool(true);
bool(false);
```

Comment: I've checked again and I think it's caused by something else regarding my build. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using `require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');`  in a script and this is failing to load a `require_once` inside `Some_Class`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Glad it helped!

What do you mean by `require_once` inside `Some_Class`? Could you provide code of `Some_class`?

Comment: I see. You should never require any class like `
require_once('some_other_class.php');`. That should be already handled by composer.

Comment: I know but tons of legacy stuff *shrugs*. I'm not sure why when I have `files` field inside composer.json, require_once fails whereas when I remove that part it works as expected...

Comment: All classes are already loaded by section `"classmap": ["src/"],`.

Comment: Classes which has a namespace are loaded. The require_once class does not have a namespace just like SomeClass doesn't

Comment: I see. I hope this helped you